# SIGSEGV Android error while using FutureTask

Tags: android, futuretask, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

While trying to use some parallel computing I encountered a following error:

```
SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x430000))
```

Part of my method that "produces" this error looks following:

```
            ...
            ...
            task1 = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
                Core.inRange(hsvMat, new Scalar(0, 120, 120), new Scalar(11, 255, 255), lowerColor);
                return true;
            });

            task2 = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
                Core.inRange(hsvMat, new Scalar(171, 120, 120), new Scalar(184, 255, 255), upperColor);
                return true;
            });
            executor.execute(task1);
            executor.execute(task2);

            try {
                if (task1.get() && task2.get()) {
                    executor.shutdown();
                    Core.add(lowerColor, upperColor, mixedColors);
                }
           return mixedColors;
```

This error occurs when returning `mixedColors` but only during Debug mode. When launching application without debug, it goes through but without any result, like this function didn't happen.
Code without `FutureTask<>` works fine, so there must be some issue with them, but I don't know what. I would appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT:

I managed to retrieve this stack trace, but still no solution found.

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@fc427ad rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1fbd017[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2014)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1340)
at ....SignDetector.filterColorRange(SignDetector.java:465)
at ....utils.SignDetector.runDetectionFor(SignDetector.java:173)
at ....view.DetectorActivity.lambda$-pl_th_mobileroadassistant_view_DetectorActivity_lambda$1(DetectorActivity.java:125)
at ....view.-$Lambda$0.$m$0(Unknown Source)
at ....view.-$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
at ....view.DetectorActivity.onCameraFrame(DetectorActivity.java:123)
at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:350)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```